# Is it worth to develop VANET simulations using Artery or Veins is enough?

Tags: omnet++, veins, asn.1

*This might not be the usual techincal question but I hope it's accepted.

I'm reading many publications but since now I did not came across any using Artery. The [Artery] tag itself has not been created yet. As the authors say, Artery is extending Veins for a more complete and modular simulation of the ITS-G5 protocol stack. Not considering the develompment complexity, I'm wondering:

- What makes a simulation reliable?
- Is there a minimum set of services I should consider and build my own in addition to see if it is sustainable from the bandwidth/throughput of the 802.11p protocol?
- Turning off beaconing functions makes a simulation still valuable?
- ASN1 encoding is mandatory or the Omnet++ Messages are enough?

Thanks in advance for sharing your experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Please share an outline of what you are actually trying to simulate? I was looking around for a simulation tool to simulate a VANET Network a few months ago and VEINs proved to be the best however it can get very complicated very quickly if you are not familiar with C++ or Omnet++. There is some pretty good tutorials available.

1. Depends on the purpose, an accurate representation of the feature/project under test.
2. There is a limited set already available through TraCi
3. Yes, in Veins even without the beacons on you can still maneuver vehicles through your simulation, you just won't get communication traffic.
4. Not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was my intention to make a general question because I'd like to understand the best practices of V2X simulations.
1. When your service works perfectly by itself, ther is no guarantee that it work with all other services ON (at least minimal required from standard).
2. Elaborate please.
3. This is not the point. Veins example is working if one deactivates beaconing but the point is to test if the WSM advertising still works when beaconing is active. See point 1.
4. ASN1 is in the standard but Artery's creators use not only that one but also .msg and own compiler.